# Using ASP.NET this.Page as Condition to hide labes in User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, user-controls

I'm new on using ASP.NET and I just want to ask how can I get the Parent page from a user control and use it as a Condition to Hide Contents

I Tried using this

```
var Pagechk = this.Page;
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
if(Pagechk == "ASP.app_car_viewnewcarsdelivered_aspx")
{
    lblCarDeliveryDate.Visible = false;
}
```

But never seems to work because of `cannot be applied to operand type of 'Page' and 'string'`
also tried the `Page` but doesnt seems to work either even if adding Conversion of `.ToString`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `Title`(*if the page name is what you need*).
you can get it as: `Pagechk.Title`. and to get the `Parent` page name use: `this.Parent.Page.Title`.

Comment: @vikscool sir i want to get is the actual page parent like `app_car_viewnewcarsdelivered_aspx` from the base.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS styling if you want to show and hide HTML content.
like:

```
<div id="test"></div>

if(true){
    test.Style.Add("display", "inherit");
}else{
    test.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: you can also do it using css classes
    <div class="@(@Model.Details.Count > 0 ? "show" : "hide")">

Comment: sir Hussain all I need is to set a condition that if the parent page is equals to `app_car_viewnewcarsdelivered_aspx` from the this.Page is that is when I will go set the visibility to false

Comment: if app_car_viewnewcarsdelivered_aspx is url of your page you can set the condition according to url using this
    Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()